# how to export checked checkbox value in csv?

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I'm exporting .csv file using php but i'm facing some issue like i'm not able to get checked checkbox value and how to set heading in top row ?

Here is my html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post.php">
    <table width="597" class="formatTblClass">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="99"><span>First Name</span></td>
            <td width="217"><input class="" type="text" name="fn" id="fn" /></td>
            <td width="99"><span>Last Name</span></td>
            <td width="211"><input class="" name="ln" type="text" id="ln" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input class="" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Check groups that you would like to receive updates about</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="intrest[]" type="checkbox" id="1" value="a" /></td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input name="intrest[]" type="checkbox" id="4" value="b" /></td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="intrest[]" type="checkbox" id="2" value="c" /></td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input name="intrest[]" type="checkbox" id="5" value="d" /></td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="intrest[]" type="checkbox" id="3" value="e" /></td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['intrest'])) {
        $name = $_POST['intrest'];

        echo "You chose the following color(s): <br>";
        foreach ($name as $color) {
            $cvsData = $name;
        }
    }
    $fn = $_POST['fn'];
    $ln = $_POST['ln'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $abc = (isset($_POST['1'])) ? $_POST['1'] : 'No';


    if (empty($fn) || empty($ln) || empty($phone)) {
        $message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
        $aClass = 'errorClass';
    }

    $cvsData = $phone . "," . $fn . "," . $ln . "," . $phone . "\n";

    $fp = fopen("formTest.csv", "a");
    if ($fp) {
        fwrite($fp, $cvsData);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

i'm explaing what my code doing 
Initally i don't have csv file so when i click first time my code create a new csv file and add the form value.
When i click the second time my code added data in new row .
this is what i exactly want .
But the main problem is i'm not able to add checked checkbox value in .csv file and the second problem is how to i add heading in top row?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not truly building your desired CSV data but rather overwriting the same variable with new data. Look at the following example (not sure if it will do what you want but it should give you an idea).

```
<?php
 $cvsData = "";   //Initialize it as empty
if(isset($_POST['intrest'])) {
    $name = $_POST['intrest'];

    echo "You chose the following color(s): <br>";
    foreach ($name as $color){
        $cvsData .= $color.",";      //Append the new color value
    }
}
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$abc = (isset($_POST['1'])) ? $_POST['1'] : 'No';


if(empty($fn) || empty($ln) || empty($phone)){
$message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
$aClass = 'errorClass';
}

$cvsData .= $phone . "," . $fn . "," . $ln . "," . $phone ."\n"; //Append the second line here

//Add header here
$exists = true;
if (!is_readable("formTest.csv")) {
    $exists = false; 
}

$fp = fopen("formTest.csv","a");
if($fp){
   if (!$exists) { 
       fwrite("This is my awesome header\n"); 
   }
fwrite($fp,$cvsData); 
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: hi @apokryfos that's working fine for me but it throws error on submit **Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\file\post.php on line 8** and it return array in csv and I want if i select multiple intrest it should be in one column not new .